# Submenu Popup Background to be Transparent

Tags: wpf, menu, popup, menuitem, .net-6.0

How does one make the submenu popup holding box/border to be transparent?

---

I have styled menu and submenus. When one selects a menu item that has submenus, one sees a grey box around the styled selections. How can I style that?

[image: Popup contains Grey background]

At looking at the styling for a menu [Menu Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/menu-styles-and-templates) I have tried multiple style overrides for the controls `Border`, `ScrollViewer` and `Stackpanel`. I attempted to override colors.

```html
<Menu.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Popup"><Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" /></Style>

    <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer"><Setter Property="Background"  Value="Green" /></Style>
    <Style TargetType="StackPanel"><Setter Property="Background"    Value="Firebrick"/></Style>
    <Style TargetType="Border"><Setter Property="Background"        Value="Firebrick" /></Style>   

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuPopuBrush"      Color="Firebrick" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key=" BorderMediumColor" Color="Firebrick" />          
</Menu.Resources>
```

---

### Minimal Example

```xml
<Menu Foreground="Transparent">
   <MenuItem Header="Item 1">
        <MenuItem Header="Sub 1a" />
        <MenuItem Header="Sub 1b"/>
   </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

In your example just change the popup color to red or transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is the only way, but you could override the ControlTemplate for the MenuItem. Basic Example:

```
        <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Item 1">
            <MenuItem.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Border Name="Border" >
                        <Grid>
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="6,3,6,3" ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                            <Popup Name="Popup" Placement="Bottom" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" PopupAnimation="Fade">
                                <Border Name="SubmenuBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Background="LightGray" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" >
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                                </Border>
                            </Popup>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Firebrick" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger  Property="IsHighlighted" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,3"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </MenuItem.Template>
            <MenuItem Header="Sub 1a" />
            <MenuItem Header="Sub 1b" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

You can now access the component parts and style individually.

Comment: I was hoping to not have to *pull the engine* to take out the spark plugs; but that appears to not be the case....  :-)